# Passing a value caputring lambda to a function which expects a function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, function-pointers

I've got a `class foo` to which I want to pass an object of type `T` together with a "deleter-like" function with signature `void (T)`. Currently I'm storing this function as an object `m_bar` of type `typedef void (*bar_t)(T);` inside `foo`.

This works without a problem as long as the function I want to use precisely matches the aforementioned signature. However, if the desired function has an additional parameter and I need to pass a specific non-constant value to it, I've tried to pass a lambda function which captures this value by value; but now I'm receiving the compiler error `cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'foo<int>'` in the example code below:
`

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    typedef void (*bar_t)(T);

    foo(T t, bar_t bar)
        : t(t),
          bar(bar)
    {}

    ~foo() { bar(t); }

    T t;
    bar_t bar;
};

void bar1(int x) {}
void bar2(int* x) {}
void bar3(int, int* x) {}

template<typename T, class Bar>
foo<T> make_foo(T t, Bar bar) { return { t, bar }; }

int main()
{
    int x = 47, y = 0;
    
    foo f1(x, bar1);
    foo f2(x, [](int x) { bar2(&x); });
    auto f3a = make_foo(x, [y](int x) { bar3(0, &x); }); // ok
    auto f3b = make_foo(x, [y](int x) { bar3(y, &x); }); // compiler error

}
```

Can we solve this issue without storing a `std::function` inside in `foo`?

Comment: A capturing lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer. So you need to use something other than a function pointer for this

Comment: `template<typename T, typename DeleterLike>
struct foo;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have 2 choices:

- Add extra template parameter:

  ```
  template<typename T, typename DeleterLike>
  struct foo
  {
      using bar_t = DeleterLike;

      foo(T t, bar_t bar)
          : t(t),
            bar(bar)
      {}

      ~foo() { bar(t); }

      T t;
      bar_t bar;
  };
  ```
- use some type erasure on the type (as `std::function`)

  ```
  template<typename T>
  struct foo
  {
      using bar_t = std::function<void(const T&)>;

      foo(T t, bar_t bar)
          : t(t),
            bar(bar)
      {}

      ~foo() { bar(t); }

      T t;
      bar_t bar;
  };
  ```

Comment: The reason why I didn't use your first suggestion was that it allows the user to pass an callable object of a different signature than `void (T)` (or, more generally as in my real application, `T (U, V)`). Can we disable the destructor when `bar` doesn't match this signature?

Comment: If signature doesn't match, you will have compile time error (once `~foo` is instantiated). you might use `static_assert` for more meaningful message, or SFINAE/Concept to expose requirements.

Comment: Ah, now I remember a second issue why I didn't use your suggestion in the first place. I need to provide forward declarations of objects of type `foo` and hence I don't know the type of `DeleterLike` at this place. Are we somehow able to provide to ctor's of foo, one which is as given and the other of the form `template<class DeleterLike> foo(T t, DeleterLike bar)` and delegate the `bar` to an ordinary function pointer somehow?

Comment: Not all callable are convertible to function pointer, C-way is to have extra `void* user_data` as parameter of the callback (which is a type erasure way)

Answer (score 0):

In the very restricted case where you know `y` value at compile-time this works:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  typedef void (*bar_t)(T);

  foo(T t, bar_t bar) : t(t), bar(bar) {}

  ~foo() { bar(t); }

  T t;
  bar_t bar;
};

template <typename T, typename Y, Y y>
auto create_lambda()
{
  return [](T x) { std::cout << x + y << "\n"; };
}

int main()
{
  foo<double> f1(1.5, create_lambda<double, int, 1>());
  foo<double> f2(1.5, create_lambda<double, int, 2>());
}
```

and prints

```
3.5
2.5
```